# How to automate power point slide duration by using OpenXML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have bunch of Power Point files in a folder. I will have to check transition slide duration is set or not on each slide, when transition slide duration is not set then add transition slide duration and store that file in a separate location. At present, I able to copy presentation document and access slide part, but **how to check and add transition slide duration then store in a separation location?**

Here is my code

```
foreach(var serverpath in serverpathCollection)
{
    using (var templateFile = System.IO.File.Open(Server.MapPath(serverpath), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) //read our template
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            templateFile.CopyTo(stream); //copy template
            using (var presentationDocument = PresentationDocument.Open(stream, true)) //open presentation document
            {
                // Get the presentation part from the presentation document.
                var presentationPart = presentationDocument.PresentationPart;
                // Get the presentation from the presentation part.
                var presentation = presentationPart.Presentation;

                var slideList = new List<SlidePart>();
                //get available slide list
                foreach (SlideId slideID in presentation.SlideIdList)
                {
                    var slide = (SlidePart)presentationPart.GetPartById(slideID.RelationshipId);
                    slideList.Add(slide);
                    //SlideDictionary.Add(slide, slideID);//add to dictionary to be used when needed
                }
                //presentationPart.Presentation.Save();
            }
            //?? store/create PPT file in a new location
        }
    }    
}
```